# Change webpack dev server entry points at runtime

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'd like to make Webpack dev server a little more robust about adapting to my build when switching between branches. I can detect when entry point files are added or removed, however I don't see any obvious way to update Webpack dev server with new entry point config.

Is there a way to define new entry points at runtime without completely restarting the server?